# Change keyboard layout in Wine?

Tags: wine, keyboard-layout

I've got some games running in Wine, but I can't figure out how to change the keyboard layout.  By default, I use the dvorak layout in Ubuntu, which isn't very friendly for most games.  I can change it back to QWERTY in Ubuntu, but when I fire up a game, it stays with my default dvorak.  How can I change to QWERTY inside my wine application?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the keyboard control panel, you can configure multiple keyboard layouts from the `Layouts` tab.  Click on `Options...` and expand the `Key(s) to change layout` section.  Pick the key combo you prefer and you should have an easy way to switch layouts.

If the `Separate layout for each window` checkbox is checked in the main keyboard control panel, then each window should remember which layout they are using separately rather than it being a global setting.

Comment: Where do I find the keyboard control panel?  I tried "wine control" for the wine control panel, but it's not in there.

Comment: This isn't a Wine specific control panel.  Pick System -> Preferences -> Keyboard.

Comment: Oh.  Yeah, I've already got that down.  It doesn't apply within a Wine application though.  I guess I have to change my default entirely?  That's a bit annoying.

Comment: Really?  I just tried it with Wine's Notepad application.  I added both US and US Dvorak layouts and set the layout switch combo to ctrl+shift.  The ctrl+shift combo successfully changed how my input was interpreted by Notepad.

Comment: Crazy... yeah, it works for notepad, just not the game I'm playing ("Within a Deep Forest").  Odd.

Comment: This may not work for older Windows applications.  I still haven't find a solution for a rather old dictionary application.

Answer (score 7):

A lot of wine programs use the X keyboard layout instead of the window manager's layout. You have to change it by running

```
setxkbmap us
```

Then change back with

```
setxkbmap us dvorak
```

Answer (score 7):

In case someone has multiple keyboard layouts - this solution worked for me.

I have two keyboard layouts: English (us) and Ukrainian (uk). The first one was set as default in system settings. However, in Wine games the letter keys (<kbd>q</kbd>,<kbd>w</kbd>,<kbd>e</kbd>,<kbd>r</kbd>,<kbd>t</kbd>,<kbd>y</kbd>,etc.) didn't work at all.

Based on **Alex**'s answer, I found the way to determine my current X keyboard layout settings:

```
setxkbmap -v
```

It showed me the following:

```
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete+numpad(microsoft)
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+ua+us:2+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)
geometry:   pc(pc101)
```

I noticed that the `symbols` line has `ua` (not `us`) on the first place. Assuming that Wine always uses the first specified layout, I just needed to change the layout precedence:

```
setxkbmap us,ua
```

And it worked. However, after reboot it was reset back to its default state. Thus, I have to do it each time after boot. I'll try to find a way to store those settings by default.

Comment: You can add it to your .profile or .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

Who use different keyboard layouts just need open settings on ubuntu -> language settings and plase English layout top on list. P.S. I'm sorry, I did it on gui, dont know terminal command ;-)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.